# BBC World - Why "Will this window really 'be' smashed" instead of "Will this window really 'get' smashed"?

Tags: word-usage

I'm uploading a picture here because I cannot provide the link of the article. It's a tweet wherein the poster has to write a tweet manually. The main article **does not** have the sentence in concern.

[image]

I want to learn why...

> Will this window really ***be*** smashed

and not

> Will this window really ***get*** smashed

My understanding:

Using *'be'* there talks about whether the glass is *tough* enough to bear the stroke of that thick stick. In an example, I can express

> Can it ***be*** broken? ~ No, it cannot. It is a 30-mm thick glass

But then using *get* clearly asks us to guess whether the event of *glass breaking* really happened!

> Will this window really ***get*** smashed ~ Yes, nobody could stop that mask man. It really ***got*** smashed.

In short, it's *being (capability)* over *getting (happening)*.

Comment: I want it. I want to get it done. Will it get done by me? I do it. It got done halfway now. I do it some more. Will it be done? I keep doing it. Finally, I got it done. It got done. It was done. It is done, and I succeed.

Comment: _be smashed_ describes the end state of the window; _get smashed_ describes the action. They both result in broken glass on the sidewalk, but the first focuses on the object while the second focuses more on the action.

Comment: @J.R. Very interesting! Does this hold with "He got caught by the police"? Or is true only for future tense statements? "You will *get caught* by the police" (emphasis on action) ? vs. "You will *be caught*" (emphasis on result)?

Comment: @J.R. truly informative. I'd be happy having it as an answer. This clarifies.

Comment: @Copper - In a way, yes. "You will _be_ caught" conjures an image of a man in the cell. "You will _get_ caught" conjures an image of a man getting handcuffed. Don't overanalyze it, though – the difference is subtle and we don't usually give it much thought. :^)

Answer (score 4):

> Will this window really **be** smashed

This is just a passive construction: BE + Past Participle. 
I don't think that the use of this construction places a special emphasis on the toughness of the glass. Maybe the guy wielding a stick will have second thoughts and will not smash the glass.

> Will this window really **get** smashed

Is also a passive construction, but more informal. This construction is used in sentences like

> He guy that smashed the glass **got caught** by the police.

The structure with **be** tends to be used to refer to more deliberate, planned actions. Compared with the **get** structure, it is more often used with an *agent* mentioned:

> Will this window **be smashed** by *this man*?

The structure with **get** puts a greater emphasis on the *subject*'s condition, and is less often used with an expressly mentioned agent. It doesn't need an agent in the way **be + Past Participle** needs it.

Imagine you've overheard a sentence said by a policeman to another policeman as you were passing by:

> The window **was broken**.

You might reconstruct their conversation thus:

> We came to the shop long after the riot. The streets were empty. I had no trouble entering the shop. The window **was broken**.

On the other hand, he might've been saying:

> We came to the shop in the midst of the riot. A man was wielding a stick. We couldn't stop him. The window **was broken**.

See? **Was broken** needs an agent ("broken *by a man*") to be less ambiguous.

But with the overheard passage sounding like:

> .. The window **got broken**.

There's less ambiguity: we know he refers to the process of breaking.

---

Reference: 
Michael Swan, Practical English Usage, Unit 223.5 ('Get' as passive auxiliary);
Quirk et al., "A Comprehensive Grammar..", Unit 3.66 (The passive auxiliaries: *be* and *get*)